# `Multiple definitions` error points to pthread.h

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Using gcc 4.6.1, I get some pretty bizarre errors at link time.  I've defined various objects in a namespace `SpacetimeAlgebra`, and the compiler claims that they're already defined in `pthread.h` and in `std::_Vector_base<double>::_M_deallocate`.  The errors look like this:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Waveforms.o: In function `~vector':
GWFrames/Code/Waveforms.cpp:4978: multiple definition of `SpacetimeAlgebra::I3'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/SpacetimeAlgebra/SpacetimeAlgebra.o:/usr/include/pthread.h:1112: first defined here
```

Obviously, `pthread.h` does not actually directly contain anything involving my objects, and certainly not in that namespace.  I seriously doubt that the error is in my code, as it compiles just fine with other compilers, and this is such a ridiculous error.

It strikes me as particularly bizarre that the "first defined" references change from pthread to _M_deallocate for objects that are defined in the same place.  I don't have any `using` commands involving `SpacetimeAlgebra`.  Is there something else I might be doing wrong?

The compiler command and full error output are [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/moble/d6b3b5db911a2ca758f5#file-gistfile1-txt).  The command was created by python's distutils.  The code itself is [here](https://github.com/moble/SpacetimeAlgebra/tree/master/CodeGenerators), in the `hpp` and `cpp` files.  (These were mostly generated by [Gaigen](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~fontijne/g25.html), with a few tweaks from me.)

On a related note, the compilation works without any trouble on Apple LLVM 5.1.  The compiler used here is on a cluster that many people successfully use all the time for some crazy compilations, so that at least usually works.

Comment: Show your code. There is no way to answer this question as-is. BTW, I didn't downvote. I would have written "-1" if I did. You were hit by an anonymous drive-by down-voter.

Comment: Probably some confusion in the compiler - I'm pretty sure your symbols are not defined in pthread, and I expect that SpaceTimeAlgebra is not part of the pthread library in any way.

Comment: @DavidHammen Code or actual linker command line? I'm not so sure if it's really a problem of the code :-/ ...

Comment: @DavidHammen No problem.  I've linked to the code in the question now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Actually, a minimum working example would be nice. Nobody wants to see thousands of lines of code posted here.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Agreed.  That's why I called it "bizarre".  :)

Comment: I don't think a MWE is really possible here...  But anyway the command line is given in the gist I linked to in the question.

Comment: I guess my hope is that this is so bizarre and obviously not related to my code itself that somebody has some better idea of where to look for the problem.

Comment: @Mike - What you gave is the second worst nightmare. The worst is no code at all. "My application dies with a segfault. What's wrong with my computer / my compiler?". The second worst nightmare is thousands of lines of code, and that's where we are now.

Comment: A MWE is always possible. If you haven't tried to make one yet, then you are not at the stage in your debugging where posting on the internet is appropriate. More to the point, without a MWE this is not appropriate for Stack Overflow because it will never help anyone else.

Comment: Note that I'm being a total hypocrite as I should not have answered this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GWFrames/Code/Waveforms.cpp:4978: multiple definition of `SpacetimeAlgebra::psI'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/SpacetimeAlgebra/SpacetimeAlgebra.o:/usr/include/pthread.h:1112: first defined here
```

You're reading the error message wrong, because it's confusing (and possibly buggy, though before blaming the compiler I'd check that you have debug symbols in *all* your `.o`s).

The error is telling you that you've defined `SpacetimeAlgebra::psI` inside `Waveforms.cpp` and inside `SpacetimeAlgebra.cpp`.

Unfortunately, we cannot see `Waveforms.cpp`, so this cannot be verified.